# How can I test a piece of code that works with files?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust

I'm currently working on a personal project with Rust to learn the language, which basically consists on translating a project I did in college in C to Rust. The project basically consists in a (very) simplified file system based on ext2, and I want to test a part of code responsible of creating a
"virtual device" (a file) and read/write to it, but I don't know what's the best approach to test it. This is the code I want to test:

```rust
pub struct FileSystem {
    v_device: File,
    size: usize
}

impl FileSystem {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> Result<Self, io::Error> {
        let v_device = File::create(path)?;
        v_device.set_permissions(fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o666))
            .expect("TODO: panic message");

        Ok (Self { v_device, size: 0 })
    }

    pub fn write_block(&mut self, block_number: u64, buffer: &[u8; BLOCKSIZE as usize]) -> Result<usize, io::Error> {
        let offset = BLOCKSIZE * block_number;

        let bytes_written = self.v_device.write_at(buffer, offset)?;
        self.size += bytes_written;

        Ok(bytes_written)
    }

    pub fn read_block(&self, block_number: u64, buffer: &mut [u8; BLOCKSIZE as usize]) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let offset = BLOCKSIZE * block_number;

        self.v_device.read_exact_at(buffer, offset)?;

        Ok(())
    }

}
```

My idea is to test the creation of the file, that the correct number of bytes are written, that the correct number of bytes can be read, etc., but this would mean I'd have to create several real files only to test the program. Is there a way to test it without having to create a bunch of files? If not, how's the best approach to test this code?

PS: any advice regarding the code I posted is also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `read_block` and `write_block` operations that you want to test do not actually require `v_device` to be a file, but something that implements [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) and [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html) traits, you can make the `FileSystem` generic:

```rust
pub struct FileSystem<T: Read + Write + Seek> {
    v_device: T,
    size: usize
}
```

Then create another constructor in addition to `new` which accepts argument of type `T`. In the tests, instead of a `File` you can use [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) which also implements `Read + Write + Seek` and can operate on the in-memory `Vec` if you construct it with `Cursor::new(Vec::new())`.

Answer (score 1):

I try not to unit test actually writing to files and prefer to have an interface (or trait in Rust's case) so that you can have an in-memory implementation specifically for unit testing. You can use that to check that you are writing/reading the correct *bytes*. You can test actually writing to files as part of a system/integration test. Here's a simple code sample to show what I mean (for the writer at least):

```
pub trait Writer {
    fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]);
}

struct MemoryWriter {
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl MemoryWriter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        MemoryWriter {
            buffer: Vec::new(),   
        }
    }
}

impl Writer for MemoryWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        for byte in bytes {
            self.buffer.push(*byte);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut writer = MemoryWriter::new();
    writer.write(&[1, 2]);
    assert!(writer.buffer.iter().eq([1, 2].iter()));
}
```